# Is there a shorthand for the IF statement in PowerShell?

Tags: bash, powershell

In bash, I often did things like:

```
[ -z "${someEnvVar}" ] && someEnvVar="default value"
```

Instead of creating a full-fledge if statement:

```
if [ -z "${someEnvVar}" ]; then someEnvVar="default value"; fi
```

Is there a similar shorthand in PowerShell without creating a function or alias?

I'd rather not write the following in PowerShell:

```
if ("${someVar}" -eq "") {
    $someVar = "default value"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`If` seems more readable to me, but you can use short circuit of OR (similar to BASH version):

```
$someVar = ""
[void]($someVar -ne "" -or ($someVar = "Default"))

$someVar #yields "Default"


$someVar = "Custom"
[void]($someVar -ne "" -or ($someVar = "Default"))

$someVar #yields "Custom"
```

Comment: Nice! `[void]("${someVar}" -eq "" -and ($someVar = "default value"))` is very similar to my bash shorthand. Thanks!

Comment: Nice trick, upvoted, but I would warn against using this in *shared* code. It doesn't show the intent of the code and it depends on implementation details. It's one of those thing that become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid Powershell doesnt have such an elegant solution as C# have:

```
Exp1 ? Exp2: Exp3
msg = (age >= 18) ? "Welcome" : "Sorry";
```

But you could do something like this:

```
$someVar = if ("${someVar}" -eq "") { "default value" }
```

Comment: I also just discovered `$someVar = @{$true=$someVar;$false="default value"}["${someVar}" -ne ""]` -- but I don't think it's very readable.

Comment: I think your example might null $someVar if it already contained a value. But you could probably follow it with `else { $someVar }`

Comment: @coderdad, yup, exactly, you could follow it with else statement

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

```
$emptystring = ""

if ($emptystring -eq "") {
    "The string was empty"
}

if (!$emptystring) {
    "The string was null or empty"
}
if (!$someVar) {
    "The value was null or unassigned"
}

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($emptystring)) {
    "The value was null or empty"
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
The string was empty 
The string was null or empty
The value was null or unassigned  
The value was null or empty
```

Comment: That's a nice summary but it's an answer to another question I think.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers yes I think you're right, I misunderstood and thought the OP was trying to avoid excessive statements in the boolean condition. It's kind of obvious now seeing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since PowerShell 7, you can use C#-like `If ? Then : Else` syntax:

```bsh
$Variable = -not $Variable ? $Default : $Variable
```

For pipes, you can now use bash-like `||` and `&&`:

```bsh
(Get-Value && Use-Value) || Set-Value $Default
```

or

```bsh
(Get-Value && Use-Value) || (& {Set-Value $Default; Get-Value} | Use-Value)
```

where `&` executes a script block (I don't know of a way to chain two commands in a pipe without passing values between them)